# Icons have poor clarity in Xamarin forms IOS project

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, icons

I am using 24x24 pixels icons in my xamarin forms ios project, but not getting good clarity. So I modified all the icons with 32x32 pixel size. Icons sizes are increased but still getting poor clarity.

**So which resolution icons are good for xamarin forms IOS project?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it has proven to be good practise to add an image in three versions.

A "small" version, being used on non-retina devices, though that is kind of legacy support by now, a "medium" version for usual retina displays and a "large" one for higher ones.

If you name your files properly, xamarin.iOS will automatically choose the right file for the current device.

For instance, I have a file "fa_home.png" with a resolution of 25x25px, "fa_home@2x.png" in 50x50 and "fa_home@3x.png" in 75x75.

Just add the files to your project and reference the first one without the @2x or @3x addition in the name.

[image]

For Android , I am using the following sizes:

- drawable - 72x72
- drawable-hdpi - 72x72
- drawable-xhdpi - 96x96
- drawable-xxhdpi - 144x144

Comment: Currently I am using only one icon, I will try adding 3 and update you

Comment: Can you provide the resolution of android and UWP icons here?

Comment: Added the android icon sizes, I am currently using in my apps, however I am not implementing for UWP at the moment.